# Deleting/Cleaning Screen-Objects with all child-objects in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, architecture

For my game, Im using

- libGDX
- Ashley (ECS)
- Box2D

Ive got a lot of screens but for simplification: `MainMenuScreen` and `InGameScreen`.

In InGameScreen Im init the ECS (Ashley) and create a lot of entities. Some have PhysicsComponent. The PhysicsSystem will catch them and call Box2D to spawn some objects based on the parameters within the PhysicsComponents.

So far so good.

Now, when the player dyes, I run `setScreen(new MainMenuScreen());` from my "Main"-Class (MyGame.java).

1. the game starts and `MyGame` loading at first the `MainMenuScreen`
2. than the `InGameScreen` will get loaded (when player presses a key)
3. than the player dyes
4. `MyGame` recognized it and loading again (throu calling `setScreen(...)`) the `MainMenuScreen`
5. When Player press key: `MyGame` loading another round (`setScreen(new InGameScreen)`)

I guess I have to do something like a complete clean up between switching screens. But how should I implement this? Just "deleting" the old InGameScreen-Object shouldent be enought, right?

- Do I have to use the `dispose()`-Method?
- Is it enough to instantiate everything new (in the `init` from `InGameScreen`) since it will instantiate all child-object new for its own like `Box2DWorld world = new World();`

Answer (score 1):

Making a new instance of a screen, each time you set it is ok. It will clean everything in your screen.

Since InGameScreen will need to reset every time you set it, it's a possibility.

But for screen that don't need to be reloaded / cleaned like a menu screen, you could use **[singletons](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/java/example)**. This way you only share one instance of the screen in your code and don't reload it for nothing.

Basically:

- Screen which need clean reload - `setScreen(new YourScreen);`
- Screen which don't need clean reload (which contain a simple menu with user interactions) - `setScreen(YourMenuScreen.instance);`

---

You can push this arthictecture by making all screens **singletons**, set up the screen (load what need to be loaded) by overriding `Screen.show()` (called on setScreen) and clean everything that need to be cleared by overriding `Screen.hide()` (called when screen is not longer active screen).

This way, all your screens are instanciated at start. Your screen load the strict necessary on show, and clear (clear collection for example, instead of re-instanciating by instanciating the screen each time you set it) what's need to be cleared when it's no longer the active screen). You will win a certain amount of time at runtime with this architecture ;)

Hope it helps !